# In react-hook-form controller HOC, how to change type of value from any to unknown?

Tags: typescript, react-hook-form, react-typescript

I'm using react-hook-form 7 with Ionic.  I used the Controller component to make a HOC for a datetime select widget like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { DatetimeChangeEventDetail, IonDatetime } from '@ionic/react';
import {
  Control,
  Controller,
  FieldValues,
  UseFormClearErrors,
} from 'react-hook-form';
import clearErrorsIfInvalid from '../../utils/validation/clearErrorsIfInvalid';
import setFormControllerImportClass from '../../utils/setFormControllerClass';

type ControllerDatetimeProps<T extends FieldValues> = {
  clearErrors: UseFormClearErrors<T>;
  control: Control<T>;
  name: string;
  label: string;
  disabled?: boolean;
};

const ControllerDatetime: React.FC<ControllerDatetimeProps<FieldValues>> = ({
  control,
  label,
  name,
  clearErrors,
  disabled,
}: ControllerDatetimeProps<FieldValues>) => (
  <Controller
    control={control}
    name={name}
    rules={{ required: true }}
    render={({
      field: { onChange, onBlur, value },
      fieldState: { invalid, isTouched },
    }) => (
      <IonDatetime
        name={name}
        className={setFormControllerImportClass(invalid, isTouched)}
        onIonBlur={onBlur}
        onIonChange={(event: CustomEvent<DatetimeChangeEventDetail>) => {
          clearErrorsIfInvalid(invalid, name, clearErrors);
          onChange(event?.detail.value);
        }}
        hourCycle="h23"
        presentation="time"
        minuteValues="0,15,30,45"
        value={value}
        disabled={disabled}
      >
        {label}
      </IonDatetime>
    )}
  />
);

ControllerDatetime.defaultProps = {
  disabled: false,
};

export default ControllerDatetime;
```

This works fine, but according to [type-coverage](https://github.com/plantain-00/type-coverage), `value` in `field: { onChange, onBlur, value },` is of type `any`.

I'd like to change the type from `any` to `unknown`, but I can't figure out how to do that.  Using `as unknown` doesn't work, and I can't figure out where to apply a type to override what react-hook-form is doing.